# If $f\in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $g\in C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$, it is true that $fg\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)?$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $n\geq 2$. Consider $f\in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $g\in C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$. It is true that
$$fg\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)?$$
If it is true, could anyone explain me why? Or, if it false, could anyone give me a counterexample?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it’s false. Take Your favourite function that is $L^1\setminus L^2(B_1(0))$. Extend it by zero. Multiply by a test function $g$  that is identically one on $B_1(0)$. Then $fg=f$ is not $L^2$

PS the dimension played no role at all

Answer (score 1):

This is false when $n=1$ and $g \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$ with $g(x)=1$ for $|x| \leq 1$. Let $f(x)=\frac 1 {\sqrt {|x|}}$. Then $f \in L_{loc}^{1} $ and $\int |fg|^{2}=\infty$. Can you construct a  similar example with $n=2$?

Comment: I know it doesn’t matter but OP specified dimension is at least 2